# Forwarding to Paypal with GET

Tags: paypal

i usually use the standard POST form on my site, with fields that the user fills out, which POSTs directly to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

what i would like to do now, is have the form submit to my own site, for my own internal programming purposes, and when that is done, my site would automatically forward the user to paypal, with the relevant field data in the URL, for example, to: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?first_name=foo&last_name=bar& etc...

this would save me from having to put the intermediate stage of the form with the hidden fields, asking the user to "click here to complete your transaction on PayPal"

hope i'm understood....

thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I don't believe PayPal accepts `GET` parameters. Have you tried building the query and testing it?

Comment: yes, i tried and it didnt work.
i am wondering if they have some kind of a tool for this.

Comment: An alternative would be to use JS to auto-submit the form with the hidden fields on your intermediate stage.

Comment: mm...  now that's an interesting idea!

Comment: Josh - thanks for this - i just tried it and it works great, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it'll work. But keep in mind that unless you involve the BMCreateButton or Express Checkout API's, the amount will be open to URL manipulation, so you *must* do a check on the paid amount afterwards.

For example; https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=blah@blah2.com&amount=0.99&currency_code=GBP&item_name=Blah+for+sale

Note:  The GET redirect must be initiated on the browser-side or via a header() redirect. You can't use cURL for this, since that's a server-to-server communication.

Comment: +1 Never tested it, and never seen an example before. Great to learn something new.

Comment: Hi Robert!  May I ask the list of valid parameters (e.g. amount, currency_code) we can pass to the url?