# How to pass data from my website to paypal

Tags: paypal, payment

I'm trying to implement a payment button from my site to paypal payment. What I want is to fill the form from my website and after clicking a paypal button, it will be redirected to paypal and get the data from my website (e.g. quantity, price, country, etc.). I did a lot of research for this but still didn't get the answer. How can I do this?

I also tried to follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311417/forwarding-to-paypal-with-get/9321406#comment11762441_9321406), but it is not enough. I mean, I also need some field to use. Please see my example below:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name">
   <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the values as a hidden values while posting to paypal. Here is an example:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@designerfotos.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="hat">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="John">
  <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Doe">
  <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="9 Elm Street">
  <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="Apt 5">
  <input type="hidden" name="city" value="Berwyn">
  <input type="hidden" name="state" value="PA">
  <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="19312">
  <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_a" value="610">
  <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="555">
  <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_c" value="1234">
  <input type="hidden" name="email" value="jdoe@zyzzyu.com">
  <input type="image" name="submit"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
    alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
</form>
```

You could also refer the link :
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/

Comment: How can I change the shipping address?

Comment: I also can't change the country.

Comment: In the link, To update address of an existing paypal account users,
<input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="1">

Comment: I've already did that. Followed by `<input type="hidden" name="country" value="JP">` And still not working

Comment: I also tried different country but still, the country is not changing.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="<country>" value="JP"> and postal code is mandatory. Refer the below link for country codes https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/country_codes/

Comment: I tried different country without postal code and still not changing.